# exist $r$ algebraic independent elements in $R$ if $\text{tr.deg}_{k} R = r$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain over the field $k \subset R$ , and we assume that $R$ is finite generated $k-$algebra ,if we define the transcendental degree for the integral domain $R$ to be the  $\text{tr}\deg_{k} Q(R) = r$ where $Q(R)$ is the field of fraction.

Assuming $\text{tr.deg}_k(R) = r$ prove we can always find the algebraic independent transcendental elements $a_1,...a_r \in R$ over $k$.

What I know so far :

Since $\text{tr.deg}_k(R) = r$ there exist $r$ algebraically independent transcendental elements over $k$  , denote them $b_1,...,b_r \in Q(R)$.(we need to realize those elements in $R$).

Since $R$ is finite generated if all elements are algebraic then $R$ itself will be a field , therefore it must exist some transcendental element.

However, I don't know how to go furthur argue that there are $r$ of them , and they are algebraic independent?

Comment: I think Noether normalization solves the problem.

Comment: I haven't learned Noether normalization so far. I have idea maybe we can do it by induction .Once we find one transcendental $a_1 \in R$ we can consider the $\text{tr.deg}_{k(a_1)} Q(R)$.

Comment: thank you I got it , I will have a look at the Noether normalization theorem first.

Comment: Can you not just clear the denominators? If $a_1', \dots, a_r'$ are the numerators of $a_1, \dots, a_r$, then if $a_1', \dots, a_r'$ satisfy some polynomial relation over $k$, so will $a_1, \dots, a_r$ by multiplying the coefficients of the polynomial relation in the $a_i'$ by appropriate powers of the denominators. Noether normalization seems like overkill unless I'm missing something...

Comment: How can you guarantee that these $a_i'$ are transcendent?Oh I see maybe use the similar argument as above 
thank you @stillconfused